# Bringing an OS X application to the front even if it's a different Mission Control space

Tags: shell, applescript, automator

What I'm trying to do is switch to an application reliably, even if it's open in a different space, using a shell script. For example, let's assume I'm in space 1, and there is a Safari window open in space 2 but not in space 1. I want to be able to switch to the appropriate space in order make make Safari active. Currently I'm using AppleScript:

```
osascript -e "
tell application \"Safari\"
    activate
end tell
"
```

But this only makes the menu bar switch to Safari, instead of moving to the space that contains the Safari window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your System Preferences -> Mission Control

[image]

Have you checked the second checkbox? (`When switching to` ....)
When yes - your applescript will work.

Also, you can change it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell
```

e.g. just add the `osascript` as an shebang and make the script executable:

```
chmod 755 ~/path/to/the/above/script_file
```